# Resizing listbox items in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, listboxitem

I would like to be able to adjust the size and height of Images in a list box while my program in running.

My list box is as follows:

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="movieListBox" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" BorderBrush="White">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel ItemHeight="300"
                           ItemWidth="200"
                           Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Image Margin="3" Source="{Binding path}" MouseDown="ImageClick_MouseDown" />
                    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding name}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

How do can you make a listbox items height and width change during runtime? 
e.g. Button is pressed and the each items height alters to "400".

Also how do you go about returning the current size of the listbox items?

**Update**

The images are loaded in to the list box in the following manner:

```
namespace Media_Console
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MediaChooser.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MovieChooser : Page
    {
...
    private List<MovieListing> movie_posters_list = new List<MovieListing>();
...
    public void LoadImages(string foldername)
    {
        foreach (string folder in foldername)
        {
...
            movie_posters_list.Add(new MovieListing(imagelocation, filmName, quality, year));
        }

        movieListBox.ItemsSource = movie_posters_list;
        movieListBox.Items.Refresh();
    }
... 

    #region ChangeItemsSize

    public bool MakeItemsLarge
    {
        get { return _makeItemsLarge; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _makeItemsLarge)
            {
                _makeItemsLarge = value;
                Console.WriteLine("Edit to large");
                movieListBox.Items.Refresh();
                //LoadMovies(blankList, "ALL");
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion ChangeItemsSize


    public class MovieListing
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string path { get; set; }
        public string quality { get; set; }
        public string year { get; set; }
        public string location { get; set; }

        public MovieListing(string path, string name, string quality, string year, string location)
        {
            this.path = path;
            this.name = name;
            this.quality = quality;
            this.year = year;
            this.location = location;
        }
    }
}
```

Updated XAML

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="movieListBox" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" BorderBrush="White" Margin="0,0,148,0">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
         </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel x:Name="OuterPanel" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Image Margin="3" Source="{Binding path}" MouseDown="ImageClick_MouseDown" />
                    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding name}"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger 
                        Binding="{Binding DataContext.MakeItemsLarge, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}"
                        Value="true"
                     >
                        <Setter
                            TargetName="OuterPanel"
                            Property="Height"
                            Value="350"
                            />
                        <Setter
                            TargetName="OuterPanel"
                            Property="Width"
                            Value="225"                                
                            />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger 
                        Binding="{Binding DataContext.MakeItemsLarge, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}"
                        Value="false"
                     >
                        <Setter
                            TargetName="OuterPanel"
                            Property="Height"
                            Value="315"
                            />
                        <Setter
                            TargetName="OuterPanel"
                            Property="Width"
                            Value="200"
                            />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: How about creating 2 templates and switch templates on button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a property to your main viewmodel, the one that owns the items in the ListBox. It looks like you're doing everything in code behind, but you shouldn't be.

```
#region MakeItemsLarge Property
private bool _makeItemsLarge = false;
public bool MakeItemsLarge
{
    get { return _makeItemsLarge; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _makeItemsLarge)
        {
            _makeItemsLarge = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
#endregion MakeItemsLarge Property
```

Now add a trigger to the `DataTemplate` to control the size, and give the `StackPanel` an `x:Name` so the trigger can refer to it when it sets the size.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel x:Name="OuterPanel" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Image Margin="3" Source="{Binding path}" MouseDown="ImageClick_MouseDown" />
        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding name}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger 
            Binding="{Binding DataContext.MakeItemsLarge, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}"
            Value="True"
            >
            <Setter
                TargetName="OuterPanel"
                Property="Height"
                Value="400"
                />
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Now how we get to the `MakeItemsLarge` property: In the `DataTemplate`, that binding by default binds to the properties of the item -- the thing that has a `name` property and a `path` property. But `MakeItemsLarge` is a property of the *parent* viewmodel, the one that owns the collection of name/path items. That viewmodel is the `DataContext` of the `ListBox`, so we go there to look for it.

If you absolutely refuse to do anything with MVVM, I can show you how to make `MakeItemsLarge` a `DependencyProperty` of the window or usercontrol or whatever kind of view contains the `ListBox`, and then how to use `RelativeSource` to bind to properties of the view itself.

Here's another option that won't require a viewmodel:

This goes somewhere in the view:

```
<CheckBox
    x:Name="ChkLargeness"
    Content="Toggle Item Largeness"
    />
```

And the `Binding` on the `DataTrigger` changes to directly grab the checked state of that checkbox. Everything else about the DataTemplate remains as above.

```
<DataTrigger 
    Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=ChkLargeness}"
    Value="True"
    >
```

> Also how do you go about returning the current size of the listbox items?

You probably don't really need that information. But it'll be the `ActualSize` property of the `ListBoxItem` instances. Chances are that'll be the same value as the `ActualSize` of the `StackPanel` in the `DataTemplate`.

## Update

Since `MakeItemsLarge` is a member of a subclass of `Page`, not of a viewmodel, let's make it a dependency property instead of the INPC/viewmodel property above:

```
#region MakeItemsLarge Property
public bool MakeItemsLarge
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(MakeItemsLargeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MakeItemsLargeProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty MakeItemsLargeProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(MakeItemsLarge), typeof(bool), typeof(MovieChooser),
        new PropertyMetadata(false));
#endregion MakeItemsLarge Property
```

And bind like so. Note that it is not a property of the data context of the ListBox. It is a property of the `Page` itself.

```
Binding="{Binding MakeItemsLarge, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Page}}"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I just have a couple of questions. 

For the first method you have listed I haven't used OnPropertyChanged() method before. What am I supposed to do here? I've tried listbox.Items.Refresh(), but the images don't appear to resize. Do i need to refresh the items in the listbox?

I can see the images readjusting sizes when using the checkbox approach, but the images appear to max out at the size listed in the wrap panel. How do you also adjust the size of the wrap panels items?

Comment: @difurious Get rid of ItemWidth and ItemHeight in the WrapPanel. The items should size themselves. ListBox.Items.Refresh() can't possibly have any such effect as you imagine. How do you populate the listbox?

Comment: Brilliant that worked for the checkbox. The MakeItemsLarge method still isn't working though. I have updated the question with how i'm loading the images in. And i'm updating the method with the following: MakeItemsLarge = true;

Comment: MakeItemsLarge should be a property, not a method. Can you show me the whole code behind and the whole XAML?

Comment: @difurious Nobody here will ever click through on a link like that. Please paste your code into the question. If there's a lot of it, you can trim it down so there's just enough to illustrate the issue.

Comment: Yup i see your point i've update the question hopefully there is enough detail there.

Comment: @difurious OK, so you're saying that when you change the value of `MakeItemsLarge`, nothing happens? Wait a minute, is your Page implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`? Or did you garble together a bunch of fragments of different classes without saying what's what?

Comment: That's the class and namespace i have implemented it in. Does it need to be implemented into a new class with INotifyPropertyChanged or does the current class need it?

Comment: In my answer, I talked about making `MakeItemsLarge` a member of the viewmodel. You know you don't have a viewmodel. Obviously it couldn't possibly work. See update to my answer. I have no clear idea what this sentence means: "That's the class and namespace i have implemented it in." What class namespace implemented what where what? I asked you a question: **"is your Page implementing INotifyPropertyChanged?"** That's either a **yes**, or a **no**.

Comment: I don't think it was, last update worked. Thanks for the help!